# После измения .js карта на API Яндекс.Карт продолжает отображать старые данные

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Сделал на своём сайте страницу с Яндекс.Картой и две метки на ней. Использую 2 файла html  и js. Всё отлично получилось. Но когда вношу и сохраняю изменения в js и обновляю страницу карты, но изменений на карте не происходит. Причём если открою в режиме инкогнито или в браузере в котором ранее не открывал карту, то изменения появятся. Либо если поменяю имя js файла и соответствующую строчку в html, то тоже изменения появятся. А если всё переименую назад, то вновь будет старая версия. Такое впечатление, что файл js загружается в кэш и при обновлении в нём данных не перезагружается. Смотрю через Safari, сайт на незащищённом протоколе http://.

В чём может быть причина проблемы? Как сделать так, чтобы всегда подгружалась последняя версия js со всеми изменениями?

Comment: файл js загружается в кэш и при обновлении в нём данных не перезагружается

Comment: консоль откройте ф12 - сеть - ткните галку про кэш. На продакшене при смене можете потом дописывать какое нить `script.js?v=2` и так далее после редактирования